# php get 2 different $strings from array

Tags: php, arrays, string

Here is my problem

```
preg_match_all('#get something#smi',$data,$get);
$get=$get[0];
$bulsay=count($get)-1;
for ($i=0;$i<=$bulsay;$i++){
preg_match_all('#<img src="http://someurl.com/demo/(.*?)"#smi',$get[$i],$vidid);
}
```

That $vidid is getting 12 ID, but some id are like this

```
14/07/12/321312491244.jpg

11/07/24/47311532132-0000.png
```

6 with JPG and 6 with png

that with the jpg is easy to replace for the video id

like this

```
141121/022227/22121/321312491244.mp4
```

but this with png need to be edited like this

```
11222/0742121/2323224/8_47311532132.flv
```

i try to get only the png urls like this

```
preg_match_all('#(.*?)-0000.png#smi',$vidid[$i],$png);
 $png=$png[1][0];
```

after

print_r($png);

i have 6 array and 6 with 11/07/24/47311532132

how can i get only the 6 with 11/07/24/47311532132

???

I try with if eregi png but it gives me the another 6 too

no idea how to fix

Comment: do you want to get only this part `47311532132` for png?

Comment: i want to get only the png $strings without  jpg.

Comment: with you reg `#<img src="http://someurl.com/demo/(.*?)-0000.png"#smi`

Comment: can you tell me what is coming in $data, $get, $vidid. i will try it on my localhost

Comment: view-source:http://www.bglaf.org/getpage.html im getting preg_match_all('#<div class="col-sm-8">(.*?)<div id="paging" class="pagination">#smi',$data,$get);  i have this from $get. you can see that i have some with jpg and some with  png

Answer (score 0):

i did it by my self :)

here how i do it

After i get $vidid

```
if (!strstr($vidid[$i], "jpg")){
 $pngid=$vidid[$i];
     $videoid = substr("$pngid", 0, -9);

}
else {
     if (!strstr($vidid[$i], "png"))
    $videoid=$vidid[$i];
    $videoid = substr("$videoid", 0, -4);

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($videoid);
```

there i have a clear png and jpg from my $string!